# Loop with tikz index problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I need a loop that ends with a test, why this one doesn't work and how use an index in this kind of loop ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\count255 = 0
\loop
\draw (0,0) -- (\count225,1) ;  
\advance\count255 by 1
\ifnum\count255 < 4
\repeat
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regardless of the specific issue, is there a reason for using the low-level `\loop` instead of PGF's `\foreach`?  Since you're using TikZ already then it would seem more natural to use `\foreach`.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how much times the loop must operate, I need a test to stop it. I don't post the test because it is MWE, Of course `foreach` would be an evidence in this case that draws 3 times a vertical line. If there is another solution I'll take it, maybe a `break foreach` but it's not clean ... ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable!  I don't think `\foreach` can handle emulate `\while` loops so that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `\the` before the `\count255` in the coordinate.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176229/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\count255 = 1
\loop
\draw (0,0) -- (0,\the\count255) ;
\advance\count255 by 1
\ifnum\count255 < 3
\repeat
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still have a problem with the stepping of the counter.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution wit `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tp = tex.print
count = 1
while count < 3 do
tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}")
tp("\\draw (0,0) -- (0,"..count..");")
tp("\\end{tikzpicture}");
count = count + 1
end
}

\end{document}
```